# Balls are dropped on a table that has 7 holes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am solving the following exercise:

Five balls are dropped on a table that has 7 holes. Assuming each ball falls independently into any of the 7 holes with equal probability, find the probability that a hole contains more than one ball, and the probability that two holes contain more than one ball.

We can define
$$
A_1 = \text{1 hole contains more than one ball} \\
A_2 = \text{2 holes contains more than one ball} \\
$$
we have $N(\Omega) = 7^5$. For $P(A_1)$ I think we have
$$
N(A_1) = \left[ \binom{5}{2} \times 7 \right] \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 + \left[ \binom{5}{3} \times 7 \right] \times 6 \times 5 + \left[ \binom{5}{4} \times 7 \right] \times 6 + \binom{5}{5} \times 7
$$
because we want 2 balls to fall together in one of the 7 holes, and for the rest to fall in different holes. It can also happen that 3 balls fall together in one of the holes, and the others fall in different holes. It can also happen that 4 balls fall together in one of the holes and the remaining one falls in one of the other holes. Or that they all fall into the same hole.

And
$$
N(A_2) = \binom{5}{2} \times 7 \times \binom{3}{2} \times 6 \times 5  +  \binom{5}{3} \times 7 \times \binom{2}{2} \times 6 
$$
because 2 balls can fall in the same hole, the other two fall together in another hole and the remaining one falls in a different hole, or three balls can fall together in the same hole and the other two in a different hole

Is my reasoning correct? I am very doubtful about $N(A_2)$.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not know what "For three balls it is similar, etc." refers to here.

Comment: fixed (I hope it is understandable)

Comment: The first part of $N(A_2)$ is counting double, otherwise your calculations are correct. You can also find $N(A_0)$ and check that the sum is $7^5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probablility of five holes with one ball is 360/2401;
the probablity of one hole with 2 balls and 3 holes with 1 ball is 1200/2401;
the probability of 2 holes with 2 balls and 1 hole with 1 ball is 450/2401;
the probability of one hole with 3 balls and 2 holes with 1 ball is 300/2401;
the probability of one hole with 3 balls and one hole with 2 balls is 60/2401;
the probability of 1 hole with 4 balls and 1 hole with 1 ball is 30/2401;
and the probability of one hole with 5 balls is 1/2401.
Computed with https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.10267407 .